# Android ImageView Fit for all device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I know this has been questioned a thousand times but I'm confuse on how can I make my image perfectly good on any mobile device. I need a landscape tablet image to be perfectly fit and not stretch and same as phone in both orientation. I'm confused. I got 2 Images 1 is 1280x800 and another is 600x900 where do I put this images so the 600x900 will work on portrait phones and 1280x800 will work on landscape tablet and phone and that images will not stretch or distort. btw I'm using adapter

Comment: You should read [Supporting Different Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html).

Comment: read that I'm even using Final Android Resizer but I'm getting stretch images pixelated images and stuffs

Comment: Please post some screen shots to show us what you are getting.